# How to plot julia inline when using Jupyter in vscode?

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter

I am trying to use Jupyter for Julia in vscode:

```
using PyPlot

a = [1,2]
b = [2,3]
fig=figure(1)
PyPlot.plot(a, b, linewidth=1)
PyPlot.scatter(a, b)

show()
```

When I run this a new window will pop up. What I want to do is to prevent it to pop up and see the picture below my codes. After doing some search it seems in Python you can solve it by `%matplotlib inline`, but how do I sovle it in Julia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `gcf()` instead of `show`.
`gcf` yields the current PyPlot `Figure` object and it will be automatically rendered by Jupyter:

[image]